# Any one knows how to apply the camera calibration matrix to OpenNI

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, Everyone:
I've already use ROS to get a calibration file (in YAML). Now, I want to use these camera parameters to my own project (3D reconstruction.) So, how can I capture data from Kinect while using these updated camera parameters through OpenNI(intrinsic, extrinsic, distortion, rectification)?  Because all my codes are written in OpenCV and OpenNI. Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31730/any-one-knows-how-to-apply-the-camera-calibration-matrix-to-openni/) by [zwsjink](https://answers.ros.org/users/2155/zwsjink/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-04-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using "openni_launch"

> roslaunch openni_launch openni_launch

with rgb_camera_info_url and depth_camera_info_url arguments. See openni_launch documentation: http:// wiki.ros.org/openni_launch#Arguments

---

Originally posted by [jdorich](https://answers.ros.org/users/7496/jdorich/) with karma: 211 on 2013-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0